# How to execute code after the block of "click" is processed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This is currectly what is executed in my webform :

```
1 - Page_Load
2 - protected void cmdSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

which, this last, is linked to an asp:linkbutton.

Than, I'd like to execute another event, even if button it is not clicked (so, not only in the postback).

How can I do it? After_Load() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try PreRender

> Raised after the Page object has created all controls that are required in order to render the page, including child controls of composite controls. (To do this, the Page object calls EnsureChildControls for each control and for the page.)
>
> The Page object raises the PreRender event on the Page object, and then recursively does the same for each child control. The PreRender event of individual controls occurs after the PreRender event of the page.

Have a look at this article about [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)